# How to use list to calculate between columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Let’s say I have a python list(like company names)
A =[ ‘a’ , ‘b’, ‘c’]

And a dataframe with date as index, column is company name, and under that column there is stock market data open, close, high, and low.

How can I make a loop to check which date a company had biggest open and close price difference?

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can start with [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18AA_NCrBm2hFbGjr0AbgJMJFCCh3NUWG?usp=sharing) & modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to find which stock on a given day had the highest percentage gain upon open versus the previous day's closing price.

If so, you can separate a mutli-index df like you describe into an `open_df` and a `close_df` and `shift()` the closing dates so the previous day's close is aligned with the current day's open. Dividing `open_df` by `close_df` then gives you a df with the percent changes of open vs prev close price for each stock. Taking the `df.max(axis=1)` of these values gets the highest percent change for each day (row), which can then be used to get the stock ticker. (Probably not the best way to do this, but it works :] )

```
# Getting some data to play with
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
stocks = yf.download(tickers='AAPL MSFT NFLX NVDA', period='5d', interval='1d')

stocks:

        Adj Close                      Close                            High    ... Low Open    Volume
        AAPL    MSFT    NFLX    NVDA    AAPL    MSFT    NFLX    NVDA    AAPL    MSFT    ... NFLX    NVDA    AAPL    MSFT    NFLX    NVDA    AAPL    MSFT    NFLX    NVDA
Date                                                                                    
2020-08-24  503.429993  213.690002  488.809998  508.809998  503.429993  213.690002  488.809998  508.809998  515.140015  215.520004  ... 483.160004  500.299988  514.789978  214.789993  495.440002  515.349976  86484400    25460100    4762200 12264100
2020-08-25  499.299988  216.470001  490.579987  510.000000  499.299988  216.470001  490.579987  510.000000  500.720001  216.610001  ... 485.089996  502.950012  498.790009  213.100006  488.190002  505.230011  52873900    23043700    5727700 7226900
2020-08-26  506.089996  221.149994  547.530029  510.920013  506.089996  221.149994  547.530029  510.920013  507.970001  222.089996  ... 492.079987  507.109985  504.720001  217.880005  492.500000  511.970001  40755600    39600800    20373700    8031100
2020-08-27  500.040009  226.580002  526.270020  505.130005  500.040009  226.580002  526.270020  505.130005  509.940002  231.149994  ... 521.250000  502.660004  508.570007  222.889999  537.780029  511.260010  38888100    57602200    9062900 7940100
2020-08-28  499.230011  228.910004  523.890015  525.909973  499.230011  228.910004  523.890015  525.909973  505.769989
```

Get the separate df's and divide open by close:

```
open_df = stocks.loc[:, 'Open']
close_df = stocks.loc[:, 'Close'].shift()
df = open_df / close_df

df:

                AAPL        MSFT        NFLX        NVDA
Date                
2020-08-24       NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2020-08-25  0.990783    0.997239    0.998732    0.992964
2020-08-26  1.010855    1.006514    1.003914    1.003863
2020-08-27  1.004900    1.007868    0.982193    1.000665
2020-08-28  1.008019    1.007061    1.010888    1.003702
```

Loop over each row to get the stock with highest open vs close

```
highest = ['none']
for row in range(1, len(df)):
    mask = df.iloc[row, :] == df.max(axis=1)[row]
    highest.append(mask[mask].index[0])

df['highest_open_vs_close'] = highest

df
                AAPL        MSFT        NFLX        NVDA    highest_open_vs_close
Date                    
2020-08-24       NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN    none
2020-08-25  0.990783    0.997239    0.998732    0.992964    NFLX
2020-08-26  1.010855    1.006514    1.003914    1.003863    AAPL
2020-08-27  1.004900    1.007868    0.982193    1.000665    MSFT
2020-08-28  1.008019    1.007061    1.010888    1.003702    NFLX
```